# No puedo evaluar varias condiciones en Any linq

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Tengo problemas al evaluar una función Any() con Linq ya que no me permite colocar 3 condiciones dentro de la función, solo me permite evaluar solo una condición, esto lo hago para verificar si el registro ya existe en BD, como puedo hacer para evaluar las 3 condiciones?

1. Obtengo mis valores a buscar de un combobox y 2 textbox

> Int32 valorCas = Convert.ToInt32(RadCmbCas.SelectedValue);
>
> Int32 valorCar = Convert.ToInt32(RadTxtNumCar.Text);
>
> string valorSent = RadTxtSent.Text;

2. Busco los valores obtenidos de los controles en la BD a través de la siguiente query.

> bool existe = entidad.CARRIL.Any(x => x.id_CAS.Equals(valorCas) &&
> x.id_CAR.Equals(valorCar) && x.SENT.Equals(valorSent));

3. La query no funciona ya que no evalúa las 3 condiciones, por lo que hago pruebas quitando las condiciones una por una, cuando se queda con una sola condición funciona pero dejando 3 o 2 condiciones no funciona, me doy cuenta por que en mi BD  los 3 valores existen y son iguales a los seleccionados en mis controles y siempre me da false.

Comment: ¿Y si agregas más información para entender mejor el contexto, por favor? Por cierto, lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: @fredyfx se ha agregado mas contexto

Comment: ¿Has intentado colocar un paréntesis englobe a las 3 condiciones? Me refiero a esto: `.Any(x => (x.id_CAS.Equals(valorCas) && x.id_CAR.Equals(valorCar) && x.SENT.Equals(valorSent)));`

Comment: @fredyfx no funciono tampo, sabras si hay alguna otra manera?

Comment: Vamos a la sala de chat, hay varias cosas a considerar: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar esto

```
bool existe = (from c in entidad.Carril
               where c.id_CAS == valorCas &&
               c.id_Car == valorCar &&
               c.Sent == valorSent
               select c).Count() > 0;
```

Se devolvera **true**, si la cantidad de registros que devuelve la consulta es mayor que cero, caso contrario devolvera **false**, para contar el total de registros se usa el metodo **Count**